# Why we have to convert data types into float before running the statsmodel for summary

Tags: python

I want to see the summary of the model but when I run the stats model it is showing below error. So I checked the issue on the internet where they are asking me to convert the data types into either float or int. I converted my data type into float then the error is gone.

But I don't understand why we have to convert our datatype into a float to get the summary of the model and also we are not specifying for which model we want to see the summary For ex I have created three models(Random forest, DecisionTree, Logistic).In the code, I am not specifying any model names for which I want to see the summary.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

x_tr = sm.add_constant(x_train.astype(float))
cls_model = sm.OLS(y_train, x_tr)
cls_model = cls_model.fit()
print(cls_model.summary())
```

```
472         exog = exog if exog is None else np.asarray(exog)
    473         if endog.dtype == object or exog is not None and exog.dtype == object:
--> 474             raise ValueError("Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. "
    475                              "Check input data with np.asarray(data).")
    476         return super(PandasData, self)._convert_endog_exog(endog, exog)

ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).
```

I am a little bit confused on the above steps.

Comment: if both y(dependent) and X are taken from a data frame then type cast both.

Comment: But I want to keep the column data type as object because that column is discrete. If you convert the column into float it will either show that column is significant or not but I want to check which factor in that column is significant.